# Java: NoClassDefFoundError in overridden method

Tags: java, android, overriding, noclassdeffounderror

well I have question about overriding. I need to override one method from Cling UPnP library. So I extended a service class and wrote the following code:

```
public class UpnpBrowseService extends AndroidUpnpServiceImpl
{   
    @Override
    protected AndroidUpnpServiceConfiguration createConfiguration(WifiManager wifiManager)
    {
        return new AndroidUpnpServiceConfiguration(wifiManager)
        {
            @Override
            public StreamClient createStreamClient()
            {
                return new StreamClientImpl(new StreamClientConfigurationImpl() {
                    public int getConnectionTimeoutSeconds() {
                        return 2;
                    }
                    public int getDataReadTimeoutSeconds() {
                        return 3;
                    }
                    public boolean getStaleCheckingEnabled() {
                        // comment from AndroidHttpClient.java:
                        //
                        // Turn off stale checking.  Our connections break all the time anyway,
                        // and it's not worth it to pay the penalty of checking every time.
                        return false;
                    }
                    public int getRequestRetryCount() {
                        // since "connections break all the time anyway", limit number of retries to
                        // minimize time spent in HttpClient.execute()
                        return 1;
                    }
                });

            }
        };
    }
}
```

For testing purpose the 'createStreamClient()' method is now same as in parent class. [Source code of parent class is here.](http://teleal.org/projects/cling/core/xref/org/teleal/cling/android/AndroidUpnpServiceConfiguration.html)

If I comment this method, it is OK and working. But if I use my overriden method, I get NoClassDefFoundError:

```
12-14 09:52:12.110: E/AndroidRuntime(20784): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread 18 (Active: 6)
12-14 09:52:12.110: E/AndroidRuntime(20784): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.teleal.cling.transport.impl.StreamClientImpl$1$1
12-14 09:52:12.110: E/AndroidRuntime(20784):    at org.teleal.cling.transport.impl.StreamClientImpl$1.createURLStreamHandler(StreamClientImpl.java:77)
12-14 09:52:12.110: E/AndroidRuntime(20784):    at java.net.URL.setupStreamHandler(URL.java:551)
12-14 09:52:12.110: E/AndroidRuntime(20784):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:286)
12-14 09:52:12.110: E/AndroidRuntime(20784):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:157)
12-14 09:52:12.110: E/AndroidRuntime(20784):    at org.teleal.cling.model.message.header.LocationHeader.setString(LocationHeader.java:45)
12-14 09:52:12.110: E/AndroidRuntime(20784):    at org.teleal.cling.model.message.header.UpnpHeader.newInstance(UpnpHeader.java:171)
12-14 09:52:12.110: E/AndroidRuntime(20784):    at org.teleal.cling.model.message.UpnpHeaders.parseHeaders(UpnpHeaders.java:68)
12-14 09:52:12.110: E/AndroidRuntime(20784):    at org.teleal.cling.model.message.UpnpHeaders.getAsArray(UpnpHeaders.java:136)
12-14 09:52:12.110: E/AndroidRuntime(20784):    at org.teleal.cling.model.message.UpnpHeaders.getFirstHeader(UpnpHeaders.java:143)
12-14 09:52:12.110: E/AndroidRuntime(20784):    at org.teleal.cling.model.message.discovery.IncomingSearchResponse.isSearchResponseMessage(IncomingSearchResponse.java:46)
12-14 09:52:12.110: E/AndroidRuntime(20784):    at org.teleal.cling.protocol.async.ReceivingSearchResponse.execute(ReceivingSearchResponse.java:54)
12-14 09:52:12.110: E/AndroidRuntime(20784):    at org.teleal.cling.protocol.ReceivingAsync.run(ReceivingAsync.java:64)
12-14 09:52:12.110: E/AndroidRuntime(20784):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
12-14 09:52:12.110: E/AndroidRuntime(20784):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
12-14 09:52:12.110: E/AndroidRuntime(20784):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

I am a little bit newbie in solving this kind NoClassDefFoundError and I have no idea what to do with it. I wonder if you could help me with it or at least direct me to some method how to determine the cause of this issue.

I only found out that this exception occures when there is some failure in static elements, but this class doesn't have them.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If I were a Java runtime environment i would complain as well :D. The runtime says it cannot find the inner inner class. Have you tried moving the inner most class one level up? Or maybe test what happens when you implement both inner classes as their own classes in an own .java-File.

Comment: They're not just inner classes, they're anonymous inner classes (both of them) to boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JVM is complaining that it cannot find the `org.teleal.cling.transport.impl.StreamClientImpl$1$1` class -- it is an anonymous instance of  `import sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler` -- see [here](http://teleal.org/projects/cling/core/xref/org/teleal/cling/transport/impl/StreamClientImpl.html) on line 77.

So it's likely that you don't have this sun package installed on your machine. But why should you need it when you didn't before.

However, I think this may be package related problem. The stacktrace points to a `StreamClientImpl` class in the `org.teleal.cling.transport.impl` package, whereas the source code you link to is importing its `StreamClientImpl` class from **different package** -- `org.teleal.cling.transport.impl.apache` (note the extra apache package at the end).

You need to sort out which `StreamClientImpl` you really want (probably the one in the apache package).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that is not finding the class StreamClientImpl, remember that the name of the class is the directories and subdirectories where it is, so the name of your class you cant find is  ***org.teleal.cling.transport.impl.StreamClientImpl***, i dont know the class, i suppose its into a library.

Remember that if you export the proyect and have your .class or .jar, the directories of your clases must be the same as the name of the class, so you must have the ***StreamClientImpl*** in a folder like ***org/teleal/cling/transport/impl/StreamClientImpl***.

I hope this maybe could help you...

Answer (score 0):

Use these classes to import:

```
org.fourthline.cling.transport.impl.apache.StreamClientConfigurationImpl
org.fourthline.cling.transport.impl.apache.StreamClientImpl
org.fourthline.cling.transport.spi.StreamClient
```

i think it will help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue than you and I've resolved it importing the library "teleal-common-1.0.13.jar" and the problem was resolved.

I am using the old library cling-core-1.0.5.jar. Maybe if you are using the new version of the library, maybe you will need import a new teleal-common library too.

By the way, I am using this library in an Android app.

That is, hope to be helpfull.